# best way to start a mysql transaction in php mysqli and PDO

Tags: php, mysqli, pdo, transactions

how can i start a transaction in mysqli and PDO? and how can i commit it? i have seen 2 ways : using autocommit(false) and begin_transaction methods , but which one is the best way? i got headache! autocommit(false) or begin_transaction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question isn't clear still I'm answering it. It is straightforward to begin and commit a transaction. In PDO, do something like this:

```
<?php
    $pdo = // connect to database with PDO
    $pdo->beginTransaction();

    // query database here

    $result = // query result
    if($result) {
        // if result is okay
        $pdo->commit();
    } else {
        $pdo->rollBack();
    }
?>
```

**Explanation: **

1. First of all, you start a transaction
2. Next, you query database
3. If result is okay, commit the transaction
4. If result is not okay, rollBack and the query will not execute

Reference: http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.transactions.php

**About Auto-commit:** In auto-commit mode, each query is a complete transaction and it is executed instantly. By default, PDO auto-commits each query. Turning off the auto-commit will need you to commit the query manually. In general scenario, you should not turn it off.

When you need to execute an important query, i.e multi-part queries that depend on each other for their final result like an amount transfer between two accounts (where you need to deduct amount from one table and to add it to another table), simply begin a transaction. PDO will not execute any query until you commit the transaction. If something goes wrong, everything will be rolled back to its previous state.

Lastly, there isn't any big difference between turning off auto-commit and beginning a transaction. By beginning transactions, you can simplify the tasks otherwise you will need to manually commit each query regardless of its nature.

I hope it answers your question.

Comment: so what is autocommit ? i can do such thing by setting off autocommit

Comment: see here [link](http://blog.ulf-wendel.de/2013/peclmysqlnd_ms-1-5-php-5-5-0-mysql-5-6-better-load-balancing/) , what is the difference of setting off autocommit and beginTransaction method?

Comment: @Mahdi I have updated the answer, check the last part.

Comment: tnx my bro , the other people just give me negative points instead of answering my question!

Comment: Glad to know that I was helpful. Regarding negative points, the community is aimed at programming issues and for explanations, there are several sources out there. i.e. the PHP's manuals themselves are a great source of information :) BTW hopefully you will find the community so helpful in your upcoming days.